# Magento products not showing in backend after importing Magento 1.3 products to Magento 1.9

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.3

I am Upgrading my old Magento 1.3 website to Magento 1.9.
I managed to setup another temp domain and have installed Magento 1.9 and the theme it all works fine,
Now i want to import all the products from Magento 1.3 to my new installation of Magento 1.9.
I did an export from 1.9 and mapped the column names in 1.3 export settings and have skipped some optional columns to export. Initially it was giving me an error of invalid tax_class_id value set though they were identical in both Magento setup. Then i skipped the tax_class_id column to export.

The problem is all the products are saving into my new Magento 1.9 DB but i can't see them in Manage Products admin page i tried to clean the cache and reindexing.

Please can anyone help me.............

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without `tax_class_id`, product doesn't show up in the backend.

Your products are showing in the database, so try to do the following:

Go to `catalog -> manage products`. Your current url will look like:

`[yoursite.com]/index.php/admin/catalog_product/index/key/[your_key]/`

Change this url to `[yoursite.com]/index.php/admin/catalog_product/edit/id/[product_id]/key/[your_key]/`

You can find the product ids in the database. When you enter this url, you can edit the product and check/edit product attributes, like tax class, status, etc and make sure alle required attributes are set.

Answer (score 4):

Also note that if for some reason the **status** field is not present in the database, then the product will not be visible in the back end. We found this problem and used Magmi to add the missing fields.

Answer (score -1):

Do only one thing, surprisingly this bug will be gone.
After importing process is done, go to the Manage Products tab, select all items which you uploaded, and select Action tabs drop down, and select 'Change Status' and hit the orange submit button.

Comment: OP says the products are not visible in the Manage Products Page, so this is not helpful